# Как создать запрос с неопределенным количеством параметров(не знаю как четче сказать) в JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Вобще есть метод который ворачивает данные с БД используя фильтры. На форме есть какието поля и в зависимости от них разные результаты запроса.

```
public List<PollEvent> getReport(String subscriberMSISDN, String operatorID, String operatorNickname,
                                     Date fromDate, Date toDate, String msg1, String msg2,
                                     int first, int pageSize) {
        List<PollEvent> result = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
                    result = em.createQuery("from PollEvent c WHERE c.call.operators.operator_avaya_id = :operator_avaya_id", PollEvent.class)
                    .setParameter("operator_avaya_id", operator_avaya_id )
                    .setFirstResult(first)
                    .setMaxResults(pageSize)
                    .getResultList();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Проблема в том, что пользователь может выбирать разные фильты и мне нужно на основании них построить запрос. Как это сделать в  JPA  я не знаю. нашел много вариантов но они все кривые для меня или я просто не понимаю ка кони работают.

Я нашел для себя одно решение но считаю его костылем. Это написать на каждый параметр свой  `if`  и проверять его на  `null` и получится что-то типо если не `null` то просто приклеивать к строке еще одно условие, типо `"AND field = :field"` и добавлять `.setParameter("field ", field)`

Но повторюсь я считаю это костылем.

Так же нашел решения через

```
public List<T> findFromNamedQueryWithParams(String namedQuery, Map<String, Object> params) {
        TypedQuery<T> query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(namedQuery, entityClass);
        if (params != null) {
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                query.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
        return query.getResultList();
    }
```

но тут тоже засада. Нужно либо создавать кучу `NamedQuery` в моем классе(что бред) либо еще что-то  колдовать. Если кто подскажет буду благодарен.

Так же нашел вариант с  `CriteriaBuilder` [ссылка](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/Criteria) но опять ничего не понял.

Comment: Если вы пользуетесь hibernate то лучше смотреть сюда https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: я веть написал что использую JPA. не хотелось бы мешать все в кучу

Comment: Эм, JPA - это API, оно само по себе не работает, нужна реализация. Но вы можете не завязывать на реализацию, а использовать только интерфейсы, тогда есть смысл посмотреть сюда: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjivm.html

Comment: Вот про JPA https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence. Где-то можно скачать в формате PDF. Java Persistence называется. То что хотите (или должны) получить часто называют динамическими запросами. И это не какая-то особая проблема JPA, а касается всех техник доступов к базе.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны сами построить запрос, соответствующий фильтру, используя JPQL или CriteriaBuilder, что Вам проще.
Примерно так выгладит строительство запроса CriteriaBuilder-ом

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
    Root e = cq.from(Entity.class);
    Predicate where = cb.conjunction(); // Надо задать какое-то начальное значение. Пустая конъюнкция годится практически в любом случае
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals("field1")) {
            where = cb.and(where, cb.equal(e.get("field1"), cb.parameter(здесь_класс_параметра_field1, "field1")));
        }
        if (entry.getKey().equals("field2")) {
            where = cb.and(where, cb.equal(e.get("field2"), cb.parameter(здесь_класс_параметра_field2, "field2")));
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
    Query q = em.createQuery(cq.where(where));
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : params.entrySet()) {
        q.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return q.getResultList();
```

Условия `WHERE` динамически формируются в большом `for`.

На JPQL на самом деле не намного проще. Главным образом потому, что нет удобных функции для построения `WHERE`. Либо надо их самому заготовить, либо без них будет слишком громоздко.
При удачном стечении обстоятельств большой `for` можно заменить на короткий как для установки параметров. Это когда поля entity и ключи фильтра совпадут, а класс параметра можно вытянуть из например value фильтра.

Так что, если не пугает, учите CriteriaBuilder.